# How does a chat app communicate with it's server?

Tags: java, php, android, client-server, chat

I currently am developing a semi-simple chat app. I want the user to be able to communicate with one other person in a private chat. Just plain text will be sent. Currently my system calls php scripts from a webpage, passes in parameters and then parses the data returned. I have it so that the client sends the message, which calls a send message script on my webserver, the script then makes a message file on the webserver and then returns a success or failure back to the client. Then for the client to view this message, it would have to call a script that checks the server for a message file with a message for him. If it finds one, it sends the message back, if not, it sends a response about not having messages.

This technique works perfectly besides the fact that the client either would have to manually refresh to check to see if he had messages, or a background thread would have to refresh every few seconds. That would be fine, however that would use data if the user was on a mobile network. Not to mention the kind of resources a background loop would pull if it was refreshing at a speed that would be convenient.

So, I decided on a second idea, this would be a server programmed in Java, which would communicate over sockets. The user would send the message as a packet over the socket and the server would check to see who it was meant to go to. If the person is online, it passes the message along to that user. However this method requires a constant connection between the client and the server and that is unreliable because what if the user is in the car and data cuts out. Or some other situation where the connection gets severed. Then it would throw errors and have to reconnect.

Anyhow, my question is which technique is better. Or are they both terrible? If so, what is the correct way of doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, what's semi-simple? Is that quasi-complicated? You do realize that HTTP is a socket based protocol, right?

Comment: Have you ever considered using [**GCM**](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)? That would be a simple solution that works really well. Wevery major chat application uses GCM or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

**AngularJs** and **Ajax** will be the perfect solution for you , try to learn

for actually real time messaging  Use **AngularJs**

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will check them out!

Answer (score 1):

If the amount of data is very less ..say 20-25 messages per day...you can  REST APIs on your server to transfer actual text messages and Google Cloud messaging for pushing notifications..Recently I followed this approach to develop private chat for one of my friend.